# Retrieving data from SQL, passing to jQuery and creating subsequent list

Tags: php, jquery, html

The basic concept of my program is:

**Page loads -> User clicks category -> New sidebar is loaded with posts from selected category -> User clicks post -> User is redirected to post URL**

I have a jQuery script which listens for a user to click a category. When they do, it passes that category name to PHP and my PHP script queries the datase.

The PHP script 'outputs' two arrays, 'IDs' and 'Titles'. The idea is that jQuery will then retrieve both those arrays to allow me to use them further in jQuery (to create the new element containing posts from the clicked category), however, I'm really struggling to pass the two arrays to jQuery from my PHP script.

I have attached the code below:

**jQuery in index.php**

```
<script>
// jQuery
$(function() { // Ensures content is loaded before jQuery

    $('.categories').on('click', function () { //When a user clicks on a category hyperlink
        category = this.id; // Set category based on link ID eg. "Cultural Development"
        load("get_posts_from_category.php", { // Retrieve all posts in category from database
            category: category // POST request information
        });
        var PHP_ids = <?php echo json_encode($post_ids); ?>; // Copy PHP array of post ID's into jQuery
        var PHP_titles = <?php echo json_encode($titles); ?>; // Copy PHP array of post title's into jQuery
        $.each(PHP_ids, function (post_id, title) {
             $('#posts').innerHTML = "<ul id='>" + post_id + "<'>" + title + "</ul>";
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**PHP in get_posts_from_category.php**

```
include 'functions.php';
db_connect(); // Connect to database

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("
      SELECT ID,post_title FROM wplg_2_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status ='publish' AND ID IN (
      SELECT object_id FROM wplg_2_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (
      SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wplg_2_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy ='category' AND term_id IN (
      SELECT t.term_id FROM wplg_2_terms t WHERE t.name IN (?))))
      ");

$category = $_POST['category']; // Get category from jQuery
$stmt->bind_param("s", $category); // Prepare SQL query with user input

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($post_id,$title);

// Instantiate arrays
$post_ids = array();
$titles = array();

// set parameters and execute. Store output 'ID' and 'Title' in arrays
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    array_push($post_ids, $post_id);
    array_push($titles, $title);
}

var_dump($post_ids);
var_dump($titles);
```

I believe the error is in my jQuery script where I am looping through each ID in the array and generating a list item as a result. However, after reading the documentation for jQuery's .each and numerous StackOverflow questions, I am at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't return two arrays.  Return a single array containing both of those arrays as children, and json_encode the outer array, so the endpoint can receive it, decode it as json, and process the children arrays accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar, I'll give that a go now.Please could you clarify what you mean by decoding them?

Comment: For "decoding" - `JSON` is a string, this needs to converted/decoded back to an object

Comment: If the ajax request expects json back it can auto decode it for you, meaning convert it from json formatted text into actual objects.  Arrays in your case.  If this is not done automatically by the ajax request it can be done with `JSON.parse(theResponseString)`

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the clarification. Having tried your solution, I think I have found the issue, potentially a fundamental lack of understanding around jQuery. Where I am calling `$.each(PHP_data, function (post_titles, post_ids) {`, should I be passing something different to the function?

Comment: `$.each()` can work over an array or an object.  If you give it an array, it will iterate over each element in the array.  If you give it an object, it will iterate over each key value pair in the object.  It depends on what you need/have for the way you use it in a given situation.